# Codeigniter 3.x giving error as Database Connection

Tags: codeigniter-3, hmvc

I am making fresh setup of CI 3.0 along with hmvc.

Made default controller as Login but after configuration I am getting error as

> Sorry. There is a problem in the Database connection.

when I print the connection object there is no loader related to the db connection.

Depending on the URL I am loading the respective db.

I guess my db related file didn't got loaded.

Anyone knows procedure to step by step debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Please check database credentials into:

```
config/database.php and
autoload the database into config/autoload.php
```

Comment: Actually i have checked the db details passing to function creating object and it seems fine.any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add db library in

```
File: application/config/autoload.php

Code: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```